# C# Loading an XML file and reading it to find a node

Tags: c#, xml, load

I am attempting to create a web service that reads an xml file and search for a node.  But every time I get an error back which says `return base.Channel.MymethodName(username);`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\CustomerDatabase.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
string searchpath = "//CustomerInformation[CustomerName'" + name + "']";
XmlNode userNode = root.SelectSingleNode(searchpath);
```

If I block out this part of the code everything else works, so I am thinking I am not doing this correct.  I have read through all the posts I can on here, and still having no luck on the issues.  Any suggestions or help?

Update:

My xml file looks like this

```
<CustomerInfo>
<CustomerInformation>
  <name>JohnDoe</name>
</CustomerInformation>
</CustomerInfo>
```

I started commented each line of my code and i think this is one is problem

```
XmlNode userNode = root.SelectSingleNode(searchpath);
```

any ideas how I can fix that

2nd Edit:
I am attempting to open the file so that I can see if the name that is inputted is in the XML file.  so pretty much a person types in JohnDoe if it exist it send a string saying person already exists.

Comment: what is the inner exception of the error?

Comment: If you have Fx3 or later then XDocument will be easier and faster. But it's very hard to match this code to the error. (How) do you test userNode for `null`?

Comment: Can't you debug through the code to find wich statement exactly threw an exception and know what exception has been thrown? Your error does not seem very informative..

Comment: You haven't said what your XML looks like or what you're trying to do with it afterwards. As Henk suggests, LINQ to XML would be considerably simpler - but you should really work out what's going wrong via the exception before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
 string searchpath = "//CustomerInformation[name='JohnDoe']";
```

Or use Linq-XML.

```
var result = (from ele in XDocument.Load(@"c:\CustomerDatabase.xml").Descendants("CustomerInformation")
                    where ((string)ele.Element("name")) == "JohnDoe"
                    select ele).FirstOrDefault();
if(result!=null)
   {
    //
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath looks odd to me. I would suggest looking here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Perhaps this would work better:

```
string searchpath = "//CustomerInformation[@CustomerName='" + name + "']";
```

As others have said, can you provide the inner exception and which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
string searchpath = "//CustomerInformation[./name='" + name + "']";
```